# Regex matching in regexr.com but not in GREP (bash)

Tags: regex, bash, grep

```
/[SELECT]{6}[ ]{0,50}[@clnt_id_n]{10}[ \t]{0,50}[=]{1}[ \t]{0,50}[0-9]{2,10}/g
```

The above regex expression is working good for below on regexr.com

```
 SELECT @clnt_id_n               = 38404
```

However it doesn't seem to work when i use it with grep as below:

```
egrep "[SELECT]{6}[ ]{0,50}[@clnt_id_n]{10}[ \t]{0,50}[=]{1}[ \t]{0,50}[0-9]{2,10}" filename
```

Comment: `egpre` is the extended version of `grep` they are not similar

Comment: [see here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep)

Comment: Your regex seems so wrong. `[SELECT]{6}` just says you want 6 letters from the S, E, L, C and T alphabet, which matches SELECT but also matches TECLES and EEEEEE and so on, which is probably something you don’t want.

Comment: @vdavid I am just testing something out and in my scenario I'll always have SELECT as the word there. My other regular expressions work perfect with egrep but i dont know why this isn't working.

Comment: you should note that regex are not same across tool/languages.. this I got from regexr.com: `RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching, and its syntax highlighting and documentation reflect the JavaScript RegExp standard.` egrep uses ERE which doesn't have non-greedy, lookarounds, etc... coming to your question, you need to give more sample input lines, explain and show your expected output.. it is not easy to understand your intention from regex you tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SELECT]{6} matches "SELECT" but also "ELSLET" or any combination of 6 C,E,L,S,T.
To match only "SELECT" you simply need to use "SELECT".

To match the test line you wrote consider using:

```
grep -E "SELECT\s+@clnt_id_n\s*=\s*[1-9]+[0-9]*"
```

'\s' matches any whitespace character like spaces and tabs.
'+' means 1 or more, and '*' means 0 or more.

Note that the regex above assumes that the number on the right side of '=' cannot start with a 0.

Comment: Just a note: the OP allowing no spaces around the `=`. (he using `{0,50}`). so, better to use `\s*=\s*` instead of `\s+=\s+`.

Comment: @silel: Nicely done, but a quibble: `egrep` is (a) [obsolescent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and (b) effectively just an alias for `grep -E`, so the `grep` tag is perfectly justified. I suggest removing the comment from your answer and using `grep -E` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to @silel's nice answer. Note that `grep -E` is the same as `egrep`.

```
echo grep -E
grep -E '^\s*SELECT\s+@clnt_id_n\s*=\s*[0-9]+\s*$' <<EOF2
SELECT @clnt_id_n               = 38404
ELECTS @clnt_id_n               = 38404
 SELECT @clnt_id_n=38404  
XSELECT @clnt_id_n=38404
SELECT @clnt_id_n=xxx
EOF2

#If your `grep` knows the `-P` option, then you could shorten even more:

echo grep -P
grep -P '^\s*SELECT\s+@clnt_id_n\s*=\s*\d+\s*$' <<EOF
SELECT @clnt_id_n               = 38404
ELECTS @clnt_id_n               = 38404
 SELECT @clnt_id_n=38404  
XSELECT @clnt_id_n=38404
SELECT @clnt_id_n=xxx
EOF
```

The above prints:

```
grep -E
SELECT @clnt_id_n               = 38404
 SELECT @clnt_id_n=38404  
grep -P
SELECT @clnt_id_n               = 38404
 SELECT @clnt_id_n=38404
```

I anchored the regexes to full lines (but allow spaces everywhere). If that is undesired, remove `^\s*` and `\s*$` from the above.